# set MaxInactiveTime in Azure is not working

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I set AzureADPolicy by

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:10:00","MaxInactiveTime":"00:10:30","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"00:11:00"}}') -DisplayName "PolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

and AccessTokenLifetime is work, my access token expires in 600,
buy MaxInactiveTime is not work, I also can get access token after 15 minute

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are using confidential clients (Azure AD application is registered as a "Web" application) rather than public clients ((Azure AD application is registered as a "Public client" application)).

**MaxInactiveTime** is only available for public clients app. It cannot be changed by using policy in confidential clients app.

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetimes-with-confidential-client-refresh-tokens).